# dependency for php-mcypt from remi repo on Centos 6.5

Tags: centos6.5, php-mcrypt

I install php 5.4 in my Centos 6.5 server withe remi repository. But if I want install php-mcrypt form this repository i obtain dependency error

```
 yum --enablerepo=remi install php-gd php-mcrypt
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.hexageek.com
 * extras: mirror.hexageek.com
 * remi: mirror5.layerjet.com
 * updates: mirror.hexageek.com
Setting up Install Process
Package php-gd-5.4.26-1.el6.remi.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php-mcrypt.x86_64 0:5.4.26-1.el6.remi will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libmcrypt.so.4()(64bit) for package: php-mcrypt-5.4.26-1.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libltdl.so.7()(64bit) for package: php-mcrypt-5.4.26-1.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package libtool-ltdl.x86_64 0:2.2.6-15.5.el6 will be installed
---> Package php-mcrypt.x86_64 0:5.4.26-1.el6.remi will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libmcrypt.so.4()(64bit) for package: php-mcrypt-5.4.26-1.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: php-mcrypt-5.4.26-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi)
           Requires: libmcrypt.so.4()(64bit)
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

libmcrypt is in the EPEL repository, which you don't seem to have installed. Install the EPEL repo and try again.